# Localytics ios push device token

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, localytics

I have implemented iOS push notifications with Localytics, and it is working, but I am confused about how they are capturing the deviceToken.

The [documentation](https://docs.localytics.com/dev/ios.html#push-messaging-ios) instructs me to call `registerForRemoteNotifications` to get the device token. Fine, this is standard. However the documentation is silent on how to handle the application delegate callback `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`. I assumed that I would need to call the class method in the SDK called `setPushToken` once the token was returned. This would be the logical thing to do. However, it seems to work without any code in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`. Are they somehow intercepting this application delegate message and passing the token to their server? Is this the intended behavior? If so, what is the purpose of `setPushToken` in the SDK?

Comment: Hi @Jeol, Could you please provide me a small demo project to handle remote notification using Localytics in swift (if not in swift then objective c should be fine). Becuase eveytime i got an crash like (localytics) -[LLLocalyticsManager startBackgroundTask]:
 + beginning critical background task                 -> and i don't know how to handle this.  Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in v 4.1 it seems they're proxying the AppDelegate with one of their own.
From their `autoIntegrate(appKey: String, launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?)` documentation:

> Use this method to automatically integrate the Localytics SDK in a single line of code. Automatic
>        integration is accomplished by proxing the AppDelegate and "inserting" a Localytics AppDelegate
>        behind the applications AppDelegate. The proxy will first call the applications AppDelegate and
>        then call the Localytics AppDelegate.

If you don't use SDK's autointegration, your supposed to call all methods by yourself, including `setPushToken`

However, it seems some callbacks are not properly getting called, for example I'm getting no `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` at all, and I can't set any push token on other SDKs.
If I remove the autointegration, everything is working as expected.